# Windows boot manager disappeared

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

When installing Ubuntu there was an error in the installation but it was installed, the problem is that Windows boot manager has disappeared and I can't boot windows.  I have all the Windows files, the only thing missing is the boot.  The Ubuntu version I have is 22.10
I have tried boot-repair and I get this error LegacyWindows detected.  Turn on Compatibility BIOS / CSM / legacy mode in your UEFI firmware and use this program from a live CD (or a live USB).  But I don't get anything in the BIOS to change that option.